# Installing Bootstrap in an ASP.NET MVC App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I created na `ASP.NET MVC` project, and the `bootstrap` version 3.3.7 was included. This is in Visual Studio 2019.

However, I need to include `bootstrap` 4.0.0. I tried through NuGet, but it said it is incompatible. So, how can I install `bootstrap` 4.0.0?

Comment: Show exactly what message you get. As bootstrap is client side, you can add any javascript library to asp.net mvc app, if not with nuget, then manually.

Comment: Have a look at installing it using NPM

Comment: This could also be of use: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/asp-net-mvc-5-install-bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right-click your solution and click 'Add', then 'Client-Side Library' to bring up the Client-Side library manager.  In here if you search for 'twitter-bootstrap' (from CDNJS) you should find the 4.0 library.

Using a client-side library manager like this should make the process a bit more manageable than simply downloading bootstrap from their website (although that is also an option).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting error from nuget the you can just add the CSS and Script.
MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:

```
MaxCDN:
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

For more info you can [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_get_started.asp)