Bootstrap table in ASP.NET Core 8 MVC
I am working with an ASP.NET Core 8 MVC project. In my project I need to implement table and I have to use table from https://bootstrap-table.com/ but I can't add this package via Nuget.
In documentation I found only how to install it by npm or yarn. I cant find this package in Nuget Manager. I also tried to download file and add files manually to project but it doesn't work. Maybe I just add bad files or miss something. What is the best way to add this package to a .NET 8 project ?

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59563854/4892466

According to your description, I suggest you could use add client library to achieve your requirement.
You could right click your solution and select add and select add client-side library.

Then inside the popup window ,search about the bootstrap-table and click install.

It will install it inside the wwwrooot's lib folder like below:

Then you could use it inside your view like below:
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap-table/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap-table/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

